# Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide - Example 2.4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

After issuing a make command to compile Example 2.4 from the Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide, I get the following response:

```
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:107: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/arch/x86     /syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated    /uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here's the content of the appropriate makefile:

```
obj−m += hello−1.o
obj−m += hello−2.o

all:
make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I'd appreciate any help, since I'm a complete noob regarding the topic.

EDIT: After rewriting the makefile, the compilation succeeded for some mysterious reason.

Comment: The spaces in `arch/x86     /syscalls/syscall_32.tbl` make it seem like some part of the platform detection code or a tool it depends on has failed.  Do you have an oddball system, shell, or `make`?

Comment: $(PWD) seems to be failing, too, so I suspect something is wrong with your installed tools.

Comment: update your kernel headers once `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like conflicts in your setup, you can do following things may work..
1)if your installation is 64-bit then check following file
vim /boot/config-3.8.0-19-generic 
             CONFIG_X86_X32=y then there is problem
it should    CONFIG_X86_X32=n
and          CONFIG_X86_X64=y

2)other option is install   remove your binutils using apt-get remove binutils and then install again using  apt-get install binutils

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the makefile solved the problem

Comment: What changed in the rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of `CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support` is spaces in the compilation directory, but that's clearly not the issue in your case.

I've had `CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support` in some cases if the kernel source directory belongs to `root` and you're running as an unprivileged user. Building with `sudo make` fixed this for me.